# Binary releases from Git

Tags: git

I was wondering how you handle binary releases. In my case, it is very old school, we just compile the source, remove the source then zip the release.

The issue when we moved to Git is that we have to during the release remove the .Git folder. This now totally disconnects the binary release to the repository. Previously with CVS, we can leave the .CVS folders without a big hassle on disk space or file size. This is not the option with Git since every project it will get bigger and bigger.

Even if there is tags, people have the tendency to move the tag for some reason and the only way to check is to have something on the binary release that will give a clue to where it was generated from in the repository. I was thinking of adding the SHA-1 number to the Changelog.txt via the Build Scripts during the generation of the binary release.

I'd like to ask if you have better ideas regarding this. thank you!

Comment: I would hope that your build process would detect change in your git repo, or checkout your repo at a given time, create binaries in a different directory that's not version controlled or git-ignored, and then push this directory of binaries to your QA/pre-production/production systems while keeping some symbols to the side for future debugging.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call that "old school" so much as "completely disregarding why VCS matters to ongoing development". I think you are hovering around the answer: don't destroy your repository, there is a wealth of knowledge contained there. People are moving tags? That's a policy problem which needs to be fixed with people, not the VCS; that is, if there is a release tag, then don't farking move it or we'll laugh and point and revert it. Someone on your dev team needs good tutorial on why VCS is a Good Thing. Alas, that's beyond the scope of StackOVerflow.

Answer (score 2):

The simpler way is to compile the source using an output folder which is *outside* the source folder.

That means:

- it is outside the git repo entirely
- you don't have to do any cleanup

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the build in your tree but without fouling up your repo, create two directories at the repository's top level; `build` and `dist`. *Add those to the  top-level `.gitignore` file*.

Have your build scripts place output under `build`, and use that to create the zip file which is put in `dist`.